# Start loop at second column

Tags: python, quantopian

I am looping through columns but keep getting an error on the first column because it seems to be datetime. Is there a way for me to start a for loop at the second column. This is using Quantopian Fundamental data

```
for column in Fundamentals.columns:  
    #print(column)  
    start=1+start  
    next = str(column)   

    Prev=Previous(inputs=[column],window_length=window_length)
    Curr=column.latest

    diff=Prev-Curr

    if(diff>0):
        pipe.add(column.latest,next)  

        if start>10:  
            break  
        #print('{}:{},').format(next,column)
```

Comment: I found the solution, the data is heavily populated with dates so the best way would be to skip all datetime datal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are already looping over the columns, you can simply use indexing `[1:]` as

```
for column in Fundamentals.columns[1:]:
```

where you skip the first column and start from the second.

Comment: how would I check if there is datetime, Ive tried isinstance(column, datetime.datetime) and type(column) the datetime type is datetime64

Comment: gotcha something new everyday